# Discord bot returns error when using slash commands with Lambda and API Gateway

Tags: python, aws-lambda, discord, bots, aws-api-gateway

I'm building a Discord bot using Lambda and API Gateway, and I'm trying to integrate it with Discord using the INTERACTIONS ENDPOINT URL. I've set up the slash commands using the following script:

```
import json
import requests

APPLICATION_ID = "x"
BOT_TOKEN = "x"
GUILD_ID = "x"

HEADERS = {"Authorization": f"Bot {BOT_TOKEN}"}

URL = f"https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/{APPLICATION_ID}/guilds/{GUILD_ID}/commands"

json_file = {
        "name": "hello",
        "type": 1,
        "description": "replies with bar;/"
}

r = requests.post(URL, headers=HEADERS, json=data)
```

The bot is deployed and seems to be working fine, as it's syncing correctly with Discord and appears connected on my server. However, when I try to execute a /hello, I get the following error:

```
Cosmic Cat:
This interaction failed
```

I have checked the logs from my Lambda function and there are no errors or exceptions being thrown, even though the logs show that the correct commands should be executed. Here is some of those logs:

```
2022-12-13T14:59:34.807-03:00   START RequestId: 58f5bfc7-a85a-494c-a92b-9f746d401ce9 Version: $LATEST
2022-12-13T14:59:34.808-03:00   event: {'rawBody': '{"app_permissions":"...'resource-path': '/discord'}}
2022-12-13T14:59:34.808-03:00   [*] running command...
2022-12-13T14:59:34.808-03:00   command hello
2022-12-13T14:59:34.808-03:00   [*] detected hello. Executing...
2022-12-13T14:59:34.809-03:00   END RequestId: 58f5bfc7-a85a-494c-a92b-9f746d401ce9
```

I have tried troubleshooting the issue by rejoining the bot on the server, adding more logs on Lambda execution, removing and adding API Gateway on INTERACTIONS ENDPOINT URL, but have not been able to resolve the problem. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

My repository can be found here: https://github.com/crisdevnull1/cosmic-cat-bot
And the link of the tutorial that I followed: https://oozio.medium.com/serverless-discord-bot-55f95f26f743